# What does a branch target like a2f <isValid+0xb> mean in objdump disassembly?

Tags: assembly, disassembly, objdump

```
0000000000000a24 <isValid>:
 a24:   83 fe 0c                cmp    $0xc,%esi
 a27:   74 06                   je     a2f <isValid+0xb>
 a29:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 a2e:   c3                      retq
 a2f:   80 7f 0b 48             cmpb   $0x48,0xb(%rdi)
 a33:   74 06                   je     a3b <isValid+0x17>
 a35:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 a3a:   c3                      retq
 a3b:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
 a40:   c3                      retq
```

From what I am understanding, it is comparing a few hexadecimal numbers and assigning some numbers to some variables, but more specifically, what do these branch targets mean?

`a2f <isValid+0xb>`
`a3b <isValid+0x17>`

---

PS. The main goal of my assignment is to reverse engineer a C program from objdump in Assembly to find the correct key to the lock, but this is just asking about the above fragments.

Comment: How many comparisons is the code making? What values is it returning to the caller? Answers to those questions will provide most of what you're looking for.

Comment: I am not sure why this is being downvoted when I just asked what are those two lines of code mean. I did not ask anyone to answer this question for me.

Answer (score 2):

> more specifically, what do these lines of code mean?

> `a2f <isValid+0xb>` `a3b <isValid+0x17>`

This is the address where the jump instruction jumps to. `a2f` is the actual address in hexadecimal. `<isValid+0xb>` is the disassembler telling you that this address is also `0xb` bytes after the start of `isValid`.

Don't ask me why the disassembler writes `0x` before the `b` but not before the `a2f`.

Note: `a2f` is too small to be the actual memory address, so presumably the loader adds this to some starting address when it loads the program. The program is assembled by pretending the starting address is 0, even though it won't be.

Comment: This could be disassembly of a `.o` which does default to 0 base address for the file.  Or possibly a Linux PIE (position-independent) executable, although I think PIE disassembly by `objdump` usually default to a fake base of `0x1000` or so.

Comment: In objdump output, absolute addresses are implicitly hex (start of each line, and in branch targets); everything else uses C syntax for numbers.  I think that's the best way to make sense of the apparent inconsistency.